# cURL refuses to ignore cache

Tags: php, cakephp, caching, curl, cakephp-2.3

I'm using cURL in my CakePHP 3.8 Instance to get Data. But cURL always gets the older (cached?) Version of the Data.

```
$ch = curl_init( $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookiefile);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookiefile); 
$url_content = curl_exec( $ch );
$url_info = curl_getinfo( $ch );
curl_close( $ch );
```

I was setting a timestamp-param

```
$url.'&t='.time();
```

but i still get the cached Data.
I also cleard all caches from Cake, but this didn't work ... anyone has an idea?

Comment: curl doesn't cache contents - ever

Comment: hm, then plz just tell me, why cURL returns different data compared to calling the url in the browser directly ...

Comment: There can be many reasons for that, from user-agent to cookies to javascript. That's what you need to figure out I guess.

Comment: it's a service, which returns JSON. there's no JS, no Cookies ... all from the same user-agent...

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming the site is controlling the cache itself. So prevent the site to send you cached data by using HTTP header with the curl.

```
$header = array("Cache-Control: no-cache");
// $header = array("Cache-Control: max-age=0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some mistakes in CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE and CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR lines. You used $curl instead of $ch.